# "How could it hurt?". Does this sentence have any special meaning other than what it says?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

I have been watching a good British drama (Downtown abbey) and this sentence is from that drama.

It is from a dialogue between a servant who is waiting for his dismissal and the head of the servants(Mr.Carson) after a dinner. So, the servant is worried that he will be fired and is asking questions to Mr.Carson trying to find out when -or if- he will be dismissed from his job soon.

Here is the whole of dialogue:

- The servant: Mr Carson, I don't suppose there's any
  more news on when you'll be serving notice?
- Mr. Carson: Nobody's going to be flung into
  the road, I can assure you.
- The servant: No, but I mean... should I
  start looking for another job?
- Mr. Carson: How could it hurt?

The dialogue ends there.

And I really can't understand what does Mr. Carson means by saying "How could it hurt"?

I have searched for the sentence on the Internet thinking it might be a phrase or a proverb, etc. But it seems it is not.

Do you know what does "How could it hurt" means here?

Thank you.

Comment: It's just another way of saying "it won't hurt". Not sure if this could be called an idiom.

Comment: @MrLister: I suspect that if the OP didn't understand the original question, they won't understand that idiom either. Chasly's answer explains it.

Comment: @ColinFine I wasn't sure - that's why I didn't post an answer - but I thought maybe the OP had misunderstood the phrasing, since it was put as a question.

Comment: @MrLister: I think 392 written instances of [*but how could it hurt...?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but+How+could+it+hurt%22) and 6620 of [*but it can't hurt to (take some precautionary action)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but+it+can%27t+hurt+to%22) are enough to say it ***is*** an "idiomatic usage". There's usually the implication that the suggested course of action might well *not* improve the situation - but there are no real downsides to doing it, so it's worth making the effort on the off-chance that it will help.

Comment: The implied part of the phrase that's always omitted is *But there's a chance it could help.* If it *couldn't* help, there would be no point in considering it.

Answer (score 3):

"How could it hurt" = "What harm could it do [to start looking for another job]?

In other words, "You might as well start looking for another job, because no harm will come of that."

> From Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English
>
> something won’t/doesn’t hurt
>
> spoken said when you think someone should do something or that
>   something is a good idea
>
> The house looks pretty good, but a fresh paint job wouldn’t hurt
>   either.
>
> it won’t/doesn’t hurt (somebody) to do something
>
> It won’t hurt Julia to get up early for a change.
>
> https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/something-won-t-doesn-t-hurt